# Oracle sql developer connect to SalesForce

Tags: oracle

I want to connect SalesForce with Oracle SQL Developer.
I using JDBC from Progress company.
When I add sforce.jar to Tools->Preference->Third-party JDBC nothing happened.
When I click "+" new connection I haven't option with SalesForce.
I don't know what I do bad ...

Comment: Remsey please see our help on how to [ask a decent question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error), we expect more information from you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run SQL queries against Salesforce, only SOQL.

If you want to use SQL then you can export data from Salesforce and import it into your SQL database. This can be done using the DataLoader for a one off or ad-hoc analysis. Or you can use a replication tool like Informatica to automate this.